# t-test vs Anova

Tags: anova, t-test

In my course, we are seeing if concentration effects the discrepancy of a mass balance sample. For example, i have 3 concentrations and 2 different processes i want to compare. There are 3 trials for each scenario. If i use a 't-Test: Two-Sample Assuming Unequal Variances' on excel, i find that the means of 2 out of the 3 concentrations are statistically different between processes. However, when i take the average value over the 3 trials and then do a 'Anova: Two-Factor Without Replication' it tells me the data is not dependant on the concentration or the process and that the variation is just due to random error.

Could anyone explain the difference to me?

Comment: Can you post the output of the models?

Comment: When you use the t-test, have you made an adjustment to account for your multiple hypothesis tests? If your significant p-values are right near whatever threshold you have for significance (probbaly 0.05), then when you make the correction for multiple tests, you'll perhaps find that the differences are not significant.